# In python, how to replace text in every row by looking up in dictionary?

Tags: python, string, pandas, nlp, text-mining

if i have dataset like this

```
    id details  
    1  I have an account  
    2  acnt is now closed
    3  he knws my acc no
```

and have dictionary

```
    d ={'acc' : 'account', 'acnt' : 'account', 'knws':'knows'}
```

How to replace all words if each row is list/string of words? Also, dataset has half million rows.

The output would like this

```
    id details  
    1  I have an account  
    2  account is now closed
    3  he knows my account no
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a brute-force job, I think.  First of all, you'll have to read the lines of the file and write the altered text to a new file.

For each line of text, go through all of the keys of the dictionary, making the needed replacement.  That part would look something like this:

```
for line in input_file:
    for word in abbrev_dict:
        if word in line:
            line = line.replace(word, abbrev_dict[word])
    # write the altered line to the output file
```

Does that get you moving toward a solution?

Answer (score 0):

quick and dirty approach

```
   with open('bigfile') as f:
         for line in f: # iterate over each line and replace words with alias
               print " ".join([d.get(w,w) for w in line.split(" ")] # your desired output
```